# Nested dictionaries getting key error/ defaultdict problem in python with Gurobi

Tags: optimization, gurobi, defaultdict

It is my first time implementing an optimization model in python with Gurobi, and I run into issues building up a decision variable.

I tried at first to use the following method with a `defaultdict`:

```
from gurobipy import *
from collections import defaultdict

def make_dict():
    return defaultdict(make_dict)

decvary = defaultdict(make_dict)

for k in K:
    for d in D:
        for i in V_L:
            for w in V_D:
                if (w != i):
                    for j in V:
                        if (w != j) and (i != j):
                            decvary[k][d][i][w][j] = m.addVar(lb=0, ub=1, obj=0, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="y.%d.%d.%d.%d.%d" % (k,d,i,w,j))
```

But later when I try to add constraints in the optimization model, the variable `decvary[k][d][i][w][j]` is of type `<class 'collections.defaultdict'>` but it should actually be 1 or 0 (binary).

So then I tried the old silly way to build the nested dictionary:

```
for k in K:
    decvary[k]={}
    for d in D:
        decvary[k][d]={}
        for i in V_L:
            decvary[k][d][i]={}
            for w in V_D:
                if (w != i):
                    decvary[k][d][i][w]={}
                    for j in V:
                        if (w != j) and (i != j):
                            decvary[k][d][i][w][j] = m.addVar(lb=0, ub=1, obj=0, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="y.%d.%d.%d.%d.%d" % (k,d,i,w,j))
```

But this time, I am getting a KeyError when adding constraints, and the KeyError always happens at the last key `[j]`

Does anyone have any idea of what's going on? Many thanks!

Comment: Btw, I cannot reproduce the key error for the second loop. Would you share a working example?

Comment: The type of a Gurobi variable should be `gurobipy.Var` not "1 or 0".

Answer (score 1):

Gurobi's Python API has a built-in method to create a dictionary very easily: the model's [addVars](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.1/refman/py_model_addvars.html) method. E.g. you could do

```
decvary = m.addVars(K, D, V_L, V_D, V, ub=1, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="y")
```

or (to also respect your exceptions)

```
decvary = m.addVars(((k, d, i, w, j) for k in K for d in D for i in V_L for w in V_D for j in V if w!=i and w!=j and i!=j), ub=1, vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="y")
```

to create that dictionary.